# Retrieving date an item was ordered on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I have the following tables:

- Order (orderID, date, shipID)
- Shipping (shipID, price)
- PO (prodID, orderID, amount)
- Price (prodID, fromDate, price)

I need to retrieve each order ID and the total price including the cost of the items in order + the cost of shipping purchased. The cost of the item has to be the cost of the item on the order date, not the most recent date. The Price table stores the different prices of a product starting at a particular date (fromDate attribute). Hence, the price of a product on day d is the price in the entry with the largest fromDate-value f such that f ≤ d. I understand I can use the command max(fromDate) to retrieve the latest price on an item, however, I cannot figure out how to get the price on a certain date. This is my code so far:

```
SELECT o.orderId, SUM(pr.price) + SUM(s.price) orderCost
from "Order" o 
INNER JOIN Shipping s ON o.shipId = s.shipId
INNER JOIN PO po ON o.orderId = po.orderId 
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 price FROM Price pr WHERE 
fromDate = (SELECT MAX(fromDate)FROM Price pr WHERE fromDate <= o."date")) pr 
ON pr.prodID  = po.prodID
GROUP BY  o.orderId;
```

It gives the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "o.date" could not be bound

I am not sure this would quite give me my desired result even if it ran though. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word in MySQL, rendering it a poor choice as a table/column identifier

Comment: And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @Defqon . . . I removed the MySQL tag.  The code is clearly SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter the `top price` on or before your order date using a `subquery` before joining.

```
SELECT o.orderId, SUM(pr.price) + SUM(s.price) orderCost
from [Order] o 
INNER JOIN Shipping s ON o.shipId = s.shipId
INNER JOIN PO po ON o.orderId = po.orderId 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 price, prodID FROM Price pr WHERE 
        fromDate <= (select max([date]) from [Order])
     order by fromDate desc) pr ON pr.prodID  = po.prodID
GROUP BY  o.orderId;
```

Answer (score 0):

you rewrite your query like below

```
SELECT o.orderId, SUM(pr.price+s.price) orderCost
from "Order" o 
INNER JOIN Shipping s ON o.shipId = s.shipId
INNER JOIN PO po ON o.orderId = po.orderId 
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(fromDate) as fromDate, max(price) as price
           ,prodID FROM Price pr  group by prodID
            ) pr 
ON pr.prodID  = po.prodID 
where pr.fromDate <= o."date"
GROUP BY  o.orderId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You havn't selected "date" in the first statement that defines "o". Perhaps something like this would work?

```
with sales as
(
SELECT 
    o.orderId
    , o.date
    , SUM(pr.price) + SUM(s.price) orderCost
from "Order" o 
INNER JOIN Shipping s ON o.shipId = s.shipId
INNER JOIN PO po ON o.orderId = po.orderId 
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 price FROM Price pr WHERE 
fromDate = (SELECT MAX(fromDate)FROM Price pr WHERE fromDate <= o.date)) pr ON pr.prodID  = po.prodID
GROUP BY  o.orderId, o.date
)
select
    orderid
    , orderCost
from sales
```